# How do I check the values of the of the residential/commercial, liftgate, scheduled delivery selections inside Magento shipping module

Tags: shipping

How do I check the values of the of the residential/commercial, liftgate, scheduled delivery selections (made by customer) inside Magento ce shipping module?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out myself.
Using the wsafreightcommon module the data is added automatically.
To access the accessorial data:

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$total_weight = 0;
        $NumItems = 0;

        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $_item) {
            $NumItems += 1;
            $total_weight += $_item->getWeight();
        }

        $checkout = $cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->_data;
        $shipOptions['weight'] = isset($checkout['weight']) ? $checkout['weight'] : $total_weight;
        $shipOptions['postcode'] = isset($checkout['postcode']) ? $checkout['postcode'] : "";
        $shipOptions['country_id'] = isset($checkout['country_id']) ? $checkout['country_id'] : "US"; // USA only by default
        $shipOptions['liftgate_required'] = isset($checkout['liftgate_required']) ? $checkout['liftgate_required'] :1; // require by default
        $shipOptions['notify_required'] = isset($checkout['notify_required']) ? $checkout['notify_required'] :0; // no by default
        $shipOptions['inside_delivery'] = isset($checkout['inside_delivery']) ? $checkout['inside_delivery'] :0; // no by default
        $shipOptions['shipto_type'] = isset($checkout['shipto_type']) ? $checkout['shipto_type'] : 0; // residential by default (extra charges apply)
```